# rails mongodb where in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

i'm trying to get positive_power_values where it's meter_id in array

```
1.9.3p194 :100 > ppv = PositivePowerValue.first
```

> PositivePowerValue _id: 518dfd25a81fc61ece8d3d23, _type: nil, deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2013-05-11 19:04:54 +0800", updated_at: nil, positive_active_energy_power_indication: "100.00", positive_reactive_power_indication: "50", use_flag: "true", **meter_id**: "**4f71181b6e92fe054b000006**" 
>   1.9.3p194 :101 > PositivePowerValue.where(:**meter_id**.in => ["**4f71181b6e92fe054b000006**"]).count
>    => 0

i wender why is 0?
i need to get positive_power_values where meter_id in array!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mongoid ?

The proper syntax would be :

```
PositivePowerValue.in(:meter_id => ["4f71181b6e92fe054b000006"])
```